# How to run on iPhone a React Native app from Ubuntu OS

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, cross-platform

Am I able to run my React Native application on a ios physical device? And if I am able to..let me ask you how is it possible?

I have created the application via 'React Native CLI quickstart' 'dev OS: Linux', 'target device: Android'..because I read: 'If you want to develop for both Android and iOS, that's fine - you can pick one to start with, since the setup is a bit different.'

I am not using Expo, because i will need the feature of reading NFC tags.

Comment: if you have a mac with Xcode installed it's possible. Just connect your ios device to your mac, start xcode, open workplace in your app project ios folder and press run. Check the quick start page for more details https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to deploy to iOS without a Mac and XCode. Since you mentioned you can't use Expo, the other solution is to use online rent-a-mac type of services which let you use a Mac in the cloud to deploy your app.